# Need unique data attribute on each ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data attribute in an ng-repeat which needs to be unique for each time the repeat loops.  Can seem to use $index in the same line that defines it or I would do that.

**Original code:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" pagination-id="uniqueId">
      {{x.country}}
 </div>
```

**Desired result:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" pagination-id="uniqueId0">
      USA
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" pagination-id="uniqueId1">
      Canada
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" pagination-id="uniqueId2">
      Mexico
 </div>
```

Comment: there will be no use with the method you are trying now. however you will be hardcoding `pagination-id` in the pagination element. better hardcode here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `$index` variable the same way you define your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" 
     pagination-id="uniqueId{{$index}}">
  {{x.country}}
</div>
```

We've been told to assume that `pagination-id` is a data attribute. If that is actually true, then the above will work fine. If, on the other hand it is an Angular directive, then most likely the value is evaluated by Angular, in which case this would be the appropriate solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in vm.country_list | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" 
     pagination-id="'uniqueId' + $index">
  {{x.country}}
</div>
```

Comment: If I try that I get this syntax error:
     
     Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [uniqueId{{] starting at [{4}].

Comment: yes.the problem is with dir-pagination. I think you are using it @mediaguru

Comment: it doesn't compile dynamic values.

Comment: You haven't given us any details about `pagination-id` attribute, other than "I have a data attribute". If it truly was a data attribute, then this would work fine. More than likely it is an Angular directive which means that value will be evaluated by Angular and you can simply pass it the `$index` variable without brackets

Comment: Yes I'm using dir-pagination, which is "supposed" to work the same as ng-repeat.  My bad on that.  Thought I'd get a better response with an ng-repeat example.

Comment: To test I setup a basic ng-repeat and used the first example @JoelCDoyle submitted and YES it worked as described. Therefore I've marked the answer correct.  I should have done a better job asking the question.  Sibi Raj is also correct in that Joel's answer will NOT work inside of dir-paginate.  I will make a new and better question regarding dir-paginate.